# How to load multiple SSL certificates on server with python with sockets

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, sni

I'm creating a server that should support SSL. I have two pairs of signed cert and keyfile for two different domains.

To add both certs to the context I've tried two things:

- Calling twice to `context.load_cert_chain(certfile=certfile, keyfile=keyfile)`
- Concatenating both certfiles and keyfiles into one cerfile and one keyfile

Both tries didn't work since it seems the server is using just one of them. My understanding is that I can use Server Name Indication (SNI) to have two domain certs in the same IP.

How can I make Server Name Indication (SNI) work with python ssl? I guess the browsers should send that info to the servers for the servers to know what certificate to serve right? How can I know what cert does the client want before calling `context.wrap_socket(csock, server_side=True)`?

Comment: You don't. You have *one* certificate with two SNI entries, one for each domain.

Comment: Are you saying that I need a certificate that it’s sni enabled with both certs?

Comment: Are they different websites? If they are two domain names for the same website then you need one certificate with both names present in the set of subject alternative names.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

you need to setup a callback for sni:

```
self.context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
self.context.sni_callback = self.sni_callback

[...]

def sni_callback(self, sslsocket: ssl.SSLSocket, sni_name: str, sslcontext: ssl.SSLContext) -> None:
        if sni_name in self.certs:
            print(f"\tSNI: {sni_name}")
            new_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)

            certfile, keyfile = self.certs[sni_name]
            new_context.load_cert_chain(certfile=certfile, keyfile=keyfile)
            sslsocket.context = new_context

        return None
```